# JOptionPane focus hiding

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
Object[] options = {"questions", "list"};

Object selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Main.mWindow, "newDocText", "newDoc",
JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
```

I use the above code to create a `JOptionPane`.

Focus is painted on primary selected option, but I'd like to hide it completley. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the answer of David Kroukamp still results in the first button focused, probably because there must be always a component with focus. The following code explicitly gives the focus to a JLabel:

```
    JLabel message = new JLabel("newDocText");
    final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, null, options);
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(f, "newDoc");
    message.requestFocus();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    Object selection = pane.getValue();
```

EDIT: If only the *painting* of the focus is a problem, you can pass JButtons to JOptionPane, after you called setFocusPainted(false) on them. You can do it like this:

```
    JButton questionsButton = new JButton("questions");
    JButton listButton = new JButton("list");
    questionsButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    listButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    Object[] options = {questionsButton, listButton};
```

But in this case you need to set up the closing of the dialog yourself. I think this is the more complicated solution.

Comment: How do I pass buttons to JOptionPane?

Comment: Added the (not recommended) answer. If you really need to go this way (have focus but not painted), then I recommend writing everything in a custom JDialog, and not using JOptionPane.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `options[0]` use `null`:

```
Object[] options = {"questions", "list"};

Object selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Main.mWindow, "newDocText", "newDoc",
JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,null);
```

As per [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29)

**showOptionDialog**

```
public static int showOptionDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                   Object message,
                                   String title,
                                   int optionType,
                                   int messageType,
                                   Icon icon,
                                   Object[] options,
                                   Object initialValue)
```

> *initialValue* - the object that represents the default selection for
>   the dialog; only meaningful if options is used; can be null

Comment: nice catch :-), though I understood the question by looking at your answer, as to what actually is OP expecting :-)

Comment: Did you run your answer? For me the first button is still selected - probably because there is always a component which has the focus.

Comment: It tajes away the borde of the selected but yes the inner text of the button looks like it still has foucs, but unless your going to have a custom panel with your own buttons, components etc its about the best